# When to use the phrase 'a enough time'?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, articles

The question is simple that when to use phrase '*a enough time*' and what's the difference between..

---

'I never had enough time for anything'

---

'I never had a enough time for anything https://www.huffpost.com/entry/i-need-coffee-schedule-yo_b_9767404

---

'if she’s given a enough time to do it' https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/19/ibm-shares-dropped-like-a-rock-today/

---

Another question is, shouldn't we use 'an enough' instead of 'a enough'?

Comment: The answer is simple too - you should never use it! I don't know where you have seen this phrase, but it makes no sense. If it did, you are right in saying that _an_ would be the correct article.

Comment: @KateBunting I read it there.   https://www.huffpost.com/entry/i-need-coffee-schedule-yo_b_9767404

Comment: It's obviously a typo.

Comment: @KateBunting well, thanks for it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to "When should I use the phrase *a enough time*" is "Never". The answer is the same in respect of *an enough time*.

Ther are **no** contexts where *enough* can be directly preceded by an article.

With an uncountable noun (such as "time" in one sense): *enough time*.

With a countable noun (such as "time" in the sense of "occasion"): *enough times*.

Neither may take an article.

What you may be thinking of is when *enough* is used to modify an attributive adjective, eg

> a long enough time

which parses as [a [long enough] time].

Comment: If edit it to 'I never had a enough time for anything' as in this article, then what would it mean 
 https://www.huffpost.com/entry/i-need-coffee-schedule-yo_b_9767404

Comment: 'if she’s given a enough time to do it'   https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/19/ibm-shares-dropped-like-a-rock-today/

Comment: Both of those are not grammatical English. Furthermore, they are not normal in any variety of English I am aware of. They are both simply mistakes.

Comment: Well thanks for it. And how to write both of these sentences correctly or just emitting 'a' before 'enough' would make them grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, just omit (not "emit"!) the _a_.

Comment: Lol yes, thanks so much..